# com.google.common.util.concurrent.Service with callback on halting?

Tags: java, guava

Is there an implementation of the Guava com.google.common.util.concurrent.Service that allows the caller to register for notification when the Service halts, either in the TERMINATED or the FAILED state?

I want to create two services, where Service #1 depends on Service #2.  If Service #2 shuts down (intentionally to the TERMINATED state or unintentionally to the FAILED state), I want Service #1 to be notified so that it, too, can initiate shutdown.

Comment: Is there some reason `Service.addListener` doesn't work for this?  (Admittedly, that was only added in 13.0...)

Comment: Does what I needed.  (I had been using Guava 12.0.)  Thanks for giving me a good reason to upgrade!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reposting this as an answer...

`Service.addListener` was added in Guava 13.0, which seems to do exactly what you want.